# Displaying information depending on hyperlink selection - tabs

Tags: php, html, css, hyperlink

I have noticed that a lot of websites display product information in special tabs such as description, specification, delivery etc.

Does anybody know what this is called and what language I can use to develop it? See picture for a demonstration of what I mean.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: try using JavaScript for tab selection and Ajax for getting data from DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preload the tab information in hidden divs, show only the first div on page load, and onclick, change the tab to show which was clicked / selected, unhide the corresponding div, and hide the originally shown div. jQuery UI will work, but for something so simple, no need to add so many lines of code to your existing structure, unless you're going to be using it often and on multiple pages. I've found that most libraries include functionality that seldom if ever gets used, so I tend to write my own simplified functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery.UI for this. It's called tabs :)

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/